Make element scroll until the top edge of its scrollable parent and then stick there?
I would like the yellow header to scroll up until it goes out of view, but then the green container should stick to the top edge of the scrollable parent rather than scrolling.
In other words, foobar should not scroll out of view.
What's wrong with my code?


<p>my page</p>
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 200px; background: red; isolation: isolate;">
  <div style="height: 100px; background: yellow;">
    header
  </div>
  <div style="height: 1000px; position: sticky; top: 0; background: green;">foobar</div>
</div>





Making a div sticky can be quite challenging. Initially, your green container was set to a size of 1000px. When attempting to make it sticky, it won't stick if its parent is scrollable and has more content to display below.
However, a solution involves placing another div inside the green container with a sticky positioning. This approach helps the element stick as intended.
Here's how you can modify your code:


<p>my page</p>
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 200px; background: red; isolation: isolate;">
  <div style="height: 100px; background: yellow;">
    header
  </div>
  <div style="height: 1000px; background: green;">
<div style="position:sticky;top:0"> foobar</div>

</div>
</div>



In this revised code:
The green container now has an inner div with position: sticky; top: 0;, ensuring it sticks correctly.
The position: relative; on the green container's outer div helps maintain the sticky behavior within its context.
This setup should effectively resolve the issue of making the div sticky within a scrollable parent container.

This is nice good job ! But is there a reason you kept the isolation or did you kept it because it was in the original snippet ?

I kept it because it was in the original snippet However it doesn't affect the sticky property , to ensure the sticky property functions correctly, the only requirement for the parent element is that its height must be smaller than that of its child, allowing it to be scrollable.

Thanks @idontknow, this though makes just the text sticky, I would need the whole green element to stick
